# Is there a concept of giving a fatter sacrifice?

Tags: animals, shiurim-measurements, korban, size

Is there a concept of giving a fatter sacrifice as opposed to a smaller one? I believe the Torah says there are different levels of sacrifices depending on your wealth (e.g. a cow vs. a bird vs. flour, etc.), but is there a concept of giving a fatter one of the same animal? (E.g. a fat cow vs. a skinny cow.)

Comment: Fatter (as in more fat in the meat) or larger (as in larger animal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *mishna* (*Menachos* 83–86) says all flour and wine offerings must be brought from top-quality produce: it lists various criteria for choosing produce, some of which, if not met, invalidate the offering. The *g'mara* (87) explains that top-quality animals, too, were chosen.